# Fill faces not showing texture

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, faces, normal-map

I added a circle in my mesh using shrinkwrap, and deleted the square faces around them and used 'F' to connect the faces to the circle. These fill faces now appear without an image texture with shading. With sculpt mode you can see them as different 'face sets', I removed that from displaying. But after this they still don't show the image texture.

I checked all normals and merged by distance, this doesn't make any difference. Hopefully it is just a simple view or merge tool I'm missing.. Does someone know why this is happening? [image]

Comment: Is your texture using an UV map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have removed faces with UV coordinates and added new faces without the UV, you are not able to see the texture, because where is no UV to map texture on faces. You need to recreate the UV map.

Comment: That worked! thanks :)